# React Hook to update State Variable in a Function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

So I have a hook that takes the input field value on change and sets the variable.

**Update**

**HooksLib.js**

```
 import { useState } from "react";

export function useFormFields(initialState) {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  return [
    fields,
    function(e, name = '') {
      if (e instanceof Object && e.target instanceof Object) {
        // Safe to assume it was an event passed in
        setValues({ ...fields, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
      } else {
        // Assume the value was passed in directly
        setValues({ ...fields, [name]: e });
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

I want to set a variable in a function call using the same hook. How would I go about that?

How to I add an event.target.id and event.target.value to a function call?

The function I would like to add it to is below.... specifically right where `///then update a variable called "fields.customerId" as the value of "customer"` is located.

**handleSignUpSubmit Async Function**

```
const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    customerId: "null"
  });

async function handleSignUpSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();



    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const customer = await createCustomer({ email: fields.email, name: fields.name});
      ///then update a variable called "fields.customerId" as the value of "customer"
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I see two options.

You can make an object that resembles an event and pass it in:

```js
const myEvent = {
  target: {
    id: 'test',
    value: 'test2'
  }
}

...

handleFieldChange(myEvent);
```

Or another way would be to include a check inside the custom hook to allow for both an event or a plain value to be passed in with a key name as an optional parameter:

```js
function(e, name = '') {
  if (e instanceof Object && e.target instanceof Object) {
    // Safe to assume it was an event passed in
    setValues({ ...fields, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  } else {
    // Assume the value was passed in directly
    setValues({ ...fields, [name]: e });
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```js
const customer = await createCustomer({ email: fields.email, name: fields.name});
handleFieldChange(customer, 'customerId');
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much Brian!  should my hook look like this to implement the check? Updated the hook up top.

Comment: Yeah I think that looks correct. Let me know if it doesn't work as expected, but I use something almost exactly like that myself

Comment: its working for passing the values of the input fields but im having a hard time getting it to pass in the ```customer``` object which is a returned customer id number that Im trying to post to a database using ```fields.customerId``` but its not coming up. Im wondering if im referencing it wrong?

Comment: What exactly does `createCustomer` return? Just an ID?

Comment: yes it just returns a stripe customer id that im storing in my database so I can reference it later. Its almost as if the ```const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({ customerId: "" });``` isnt populating.

Comment: There's a lot that could be going on potentially. If you had a codepen or something I could speak more confidently, but one thought is that you're trying to access the updated state values too soon. Setting state is async, so if you're trying to reference the updated `fields` within the same `handleSignUpSubmit` function, they will almost certainly not have the updated `customerId` yet. It won't be available until the next render. But I'm not sure that's the problem you're having without seeing the big picture.

Comment: I do believe that could possibly be my issue because if I set the initial value to null, I get an error from my database saying " value for stripe must not be null", but if I try again it passes the customer id value to stripe on the second try.